# Obter o valor do item selecionado em uma ComboBox em asp clássico

Tags: javascript, asp

Eu tenho duas combobox, preciso obter o id de uma para carregar a outra a partir do item que foi selecionado na combobox1,como poderia fazer isso através de uma função javascript.

```
<select id="cb_catinsumo" class="combo" name="cb_catinsumo" class="combo2">
    <option value="">Selecione uma categoria</option>
    <%monta combo de categoria de insumos sSQL="SELECT categoria_insumo FROM tb_catinsumo ORDER BY categoria_insumo" oQueryCatInsumo.Open sSQL, oConexao IF NOT oQueryCatInsumo.EOF THEN oQueryCatInsumo.MoveFirst DO until oQueryCatInsumo.EOF%>
        <option value="<%=oQueryCatInsumo(" categoria_insumo ").value %>">
            <%=oQueryCatInsumo( "categoria_insumo").value %>
        </option>
        <% oQueryCatInsumo.MoveNext LOOP ELSE %>//sem categorias cadastradas
            <option value="">NÃO HÁ CATEGORIAS CADASTRADAS</option>
            <% END IF %>
</select>
```

Comment: Pode colocar o seu HTML? senão vamos responder a imaginar o seu código.

Comment: @Sergio,meu código é esse onde preenche a primeira combo,estou aprendendo a colocar códigos nas perguntas, ai ficou um pouco bagunçado,

Comment: Everton, não tem problema. Pode colocar o código, depois selecionar tudo e fazer CTR+K, para fazer um TAB ao código todo.

Comment: Entendi @Sergio, através desse código teria alguma ideia de como me ajudar?

Comment: Everton, ASP não é o meu forte, mas esse select é exportado correctamente, certo? e você quer chamar outro select consoante a escolha deste. Então precisa usar ajax. Dê uns minutos que certamente alguém mais seguro do que eu em ASP vai ajudar mais. O importante é você explicar a pergunta o melhor possível.

Comment: Sim ele é exportado corretamente,ok obrigado por me ajudar até esse momento.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Quando seu combobox estiver montado ficará parecido com a seguinte estrutura:

```
<select id="cb_catinsumo">
  <option value="1">item1</option>
  <option value="2" selected="selected">item2</option> /*atente que aqui o item está selecionado*/
  <option value="3">item3</option>
</select>
```

Abaixo o código javascript para capturar o VALUE e o TEXTO:

**1) RECUPERA O VALUE DO ITEM SELECIONADO**

```
var e = document.getElementById("cb_catinsumo");
var itemSelecionado = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

**2) RECUPERA O TEXTO DO ITEM SELECIONADO**

```
var e = document.getElementById("cb_catinsumo");
var itemSelecionado = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
```

Existem outras formas de se capturar os valores, porém essa acredito que atende totalmente sua necessidade, tem formas mais rápidas, por exemplo com jQuery, caso não conheça de uma pesquisada sobre pois é muito mais produtivo em algumas situações.

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda!